# the package conflicts with an existing package by the same name

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, build.gradle, android-install-apk

I have created two applications.
The 2 handle the same structure.
They have different keystores and different packages, so why do I get this error?

[image]

Comment: You need to add to your question both the app module build.gradle files and the AndroidManifest.xml